# Is there any Maximum limit folder+files count per Team Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there any Maximum limit folder+files count per Team Site on SharePoint online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Microsoft's  A list can have up to 30 million items and a library can have up to 30 million files and folders.

See [complete details here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Online-limits-and-quotas-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498)

But keep in mind there list view threshold limit, which 5k. So you have to plan your large list and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

This information is easy to find by searching Microsoft's​ site.

> Items and files - A list can have up to 30 million items and a library
>   can have up to 30 million files and folders. Views can have up to 12
>   lookup columns. To learn more about other restrictions for viewing
>   large lists, see Manage large lists and libraries in Office 365. A
>   file's entire path, including its name, must be fewer than 400
>   characters. For information about characters that can't be used in
>   file names, see Invalid characters in file and folder names. For
>   information about blocked file name extensions, see Types of files
>   that cannot be added to a list or library

Ref: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SharePoint-Online-limits-and-quotas-8F34FF47-B749-408B-ABC0-B605E1F6D498

Comment: While link may answer the question, but it is still necessary to include essential part of the link into the answer. Because once the link changed or expired the answer become useless.  :-)

Comment: True, Akasha, but just as the link might change, so might the answer, and since this information is easy to find from a web search why ask for it here? It's like asking, "what time is it?"